# Qt designer plugin (custom widget) in Eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, plugins, qt4, designer

I have made custom widget plugin, which is recognized and visible in Qt designer, but Qt creator and Qt eclipse integration doesn't show it.

Does anyone have ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Qt Creator and the Qt Eclipse integration have different versions of designer that they use.  (I know this is the case for Creator.)  Since they are using different designer applications, they are probably also looking in a different location for the plugins than does the standard Designer program.  My first suggestion would be to try to find where that location is, and copy your plugin there.

If the copied plugin doesn't work, you probably have somewhat incompatible versions of designer for one or the other.  That will take a bit more research, but could likely be overcome with a bit more research.

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank the asker and both responders for helping me figure this out (and also curse Nokia for not making this work right out of the box - the first two days of my Qt developer experience was Googling pieces of the answer).

First, creator [does look elsewhere](http://lists.trolltech.com/pipermail/qt-creator/2009-February/002020.html) - at C:\Qt\bin\designer in Windows (should be .../bin/designer in Linux - do a 'find . -name libqwebview.so').

Second, there is a likely incompatibility issue on Windows, because [QtCreator compiles plugins with mingw, and QtCreator is likely compiled with Visual Studio](http://www.gnome-look.org/knowledgebase/?id=160&PHPSESSID=6).  The fix is to compile QtCreator with mingw.